# Does tidylib damage my HTML file?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I am using python 3.5 and in some cases, when I call tidylib.tidy_document 
on an HTML file, the '/' character at the end of the <link ../> tag in the 
header is getting  removed. Tidylib does not give any errors or warnings when 
it removes this character.

The HTML file I am using is part of an Epub generated with writer2epub. The 
error occurs in almost all files in this Epub. The only exceptions are very 
short ones (e.g. titlepage of the document). The error is the same in all 
affected files.

I suspected a problem with the use of carriage returns (0x0d) instead of
linefeeds (0x0a), but changing them doesn't make a difference. I also see that the file contains various other non-ASCII characters, so maybe they're to blame. Googling for unicode problems with tidylib didn't turn up anything that seems to relate to this problem.

I have uploaded a [test file](http://pastebin.com/PKnRzn0K) that reproduces the problem with the following code:

```
import re
from tidylib import tidy_document



def printLink(html):
    """ Print the <link> tag from the HTML header """
    for line in html.split('\n'):
        match = re.search('<link[^>]+>', line)
        if match is not None:
            print(match.group(0))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    fname = 'test04.xhtml'
    print(fname)
    with open(fname, 'r') as fh:
        html = fh.read()

    print('checkpoint 01')
    printLink(html)
    newHtml, errors = tidy_document(html)
    print('checkpoint 02')
    printLink(newHtml)
```

If the problem is reproduced, the output will be:

> <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/style001.css" type="text/css" />

at checkpoint 01 and

> <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/style001.css" type="text/css">

at checkpoint 02.

What is causing tidylib to remove this one '/' character?

Comment: Are these files HTML or XHTML? `<link ../>` is an XHTML style of tag.  Maybe passing [output -xhtml](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#output-xhtml) will help.

Comment: @PM_2Ring it does help, but shouldn't tidylib see that it's dealing with xhtml from the header of the file? Also in other cases tidylib does not remove the '/' even without any additional keywords.

Comment: I agree that it's a bit strange, and it makes me wonder what other little quirks tidylib has, but at least you have a workaround for this quirk.